# CasperJS to loop again until to get data

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I have function written in CasperJS to set data on a TextBox and click button then extract data from the page.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
verbose: false,
pageSettings: {
    loadImages:  false,
    loadPlugins: false
}
});

casper.start("www.testsite.com", function(){
casper.thenEvaluate(function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('inputfield')[0].value="set data";//google.com
    document.querySelector('form[name="single_check_form"]').submit();
}).then(function(){
    var data = this.evaluate(function(){
        return document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[13].childNodes[3].innerHTML.replace("- ","").replace("<br>","");
    });
    casper.echo("Data found : "+data);
});
});
```

The above function is working file, in the webpage after the click i get 'String' or 'Empty String' but somethings the i get 'null' as result.

So, how to loop back until i get data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use recursion, because CasperJS steps can be nested.

```
var data = null;
function getData(){
    casper.thenOpen("www.testsite.com").thenEvaluate(function(){
        document.getElementsByClassName('inputfield')[0].value="set data";//google.com
        document.querySelector('form[name="single_check_form"]').submit();
    }).then(function(){
        data = this.evaluate(function(){
            return document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[13].childNodes[3].innerHTML.replace("- ","").replace("<br>","");
        });
        if (data == null) {
            getData();
        }
    });
}

casper.start().then(getData).then(function(){
    casper.echo("Data found : "+data);
}).run();
```